# Create link to views page that preselects the filters of an entire vocabulary?

Tags: views

I have a view that filters by different taxonomy terms, using multiple vocabularies. Im using the better exposed filter module.

I need different links to this view page which make different options pre-selected. By copying the url from when 1 term is selected I can easily make a link which works in this way:

my-site/resources?tid%5B%5D=22&keys=

I also need to make a link where all the terms from a vocabulary are selected. The client for this website will be able to add new terms to this vocabulary. If I simply copy the url with all the terms selected then this wont select a new term when its created.

How can I create a link to the view page which preselects all the terms from a vocbulary, that will still select all the terms when new ones are created?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the URL provided:

```
function MODULE_NAME_build_taxonomy_views_link($taxonomy_tid) {
  $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_load($taxonomy_tid);
  if (!$vocabulary) {
    return;
  }
  $term_ids = array();
  foreach (taxonomy_get_tree($taxonomy_tid) as $term) {
    $term_ids['tid'][] = $term->tid;
  }

  return l($vocabulary->name, 'resources', array('query' => $term_ids));
}
```